# AWK printing bash variable more than once

Tags: bash, variables, command-line, awk

I'm trying to utilize an AWK one liner that uses a bash variable. The problem is its being printed more then once or giving out an error. The bash variable looks like this (without the echo line):

```
echo "$time"
49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
```

The AWK line I'm trying to use is this:

```
awk -v time="$time" -F, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5=time}' file
```

The output is this:

```
SantaClara 6/7/2015 D 4 49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
SantaClara 5/29/2015 D 5 49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
SantaClara 5/21/2015 D 5 49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
SantaClara 4/29/2015 D 5 49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
SantaClara 4/22/2015 D 5 49.80
63.4
61
60.4
61
```

And I'm looking for this:

```
SantaClara 6/7/2015 D 4 49.80
SantaClara 5/29/2015 D 5 63.40
SantaClara 5/21/2015 D 5 61
SantaClara 4/29/2015 D 5 60.4
SantaClara 4/22/2015 D 5 61
```

I've several variations on the AWK line and have only gotten errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are very confused about awk syntax and semantics. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I just downloaded it now and will be reading it this week.

Answer (score 4):

Use `paste` instead:

```
$ paste file <(echo "$time")
```

Use the `-d` switch if you want a specific delimiter (tab is the default).

Answer (score 1):

In case you want an awk only solution:

```
awk -F= 'FNR==NR{a[++i]=$0;next} {print $0, a[FNR]}' <(echo "$time") file
SantaClara 6/7/2015 D 4 49.80
SantaClara 5/29/2015 D 5 63.4
SantaClara 5/21/2015 D 5 61
SantaClara 4/29/2015 D 5 60.4
SantaClara 4/22/2015 D 5 61
```